# Confusion with java objects

Tags: java, object

I am a beginner in java and I am currently using Netbeans IDE and I have some confusion here.
I wrote down the following codes:

```
public class Try {

    public static int AA;
    public static int BB;

    Try(int a, int b)
    {
        AA=a;
        BB=b;
    }

    int calculate()
    {
        int c;
        c=Try.AA + Try.BB;
        System.out.println(c);
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Try a = new Try(1,2);
        Try b = new Try(2,3);
        a.calculate();
        b.calculate();
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

Well, just a simple program that adds two integers and here is the output:

```
5
5
```

I was expecting it to be

```
3
5
```

So, where have i gone wrong? [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2pmI.png)

Comment: Don't make instance variables static, i.e. `public int AA;` instead of `public static int AA;` etc. (and have a look on the naming conventions and how to use access modifiers like `public` correctly - that's not directly related to your problem but you should learn that as well).

Comment: Thank you very much! I corrected my code and i will have a look on the naming conventions. I guess i need to buy a proper book.

Answer (score 4):

`AA` and `BB` are `static` which means they belong to the *class*, not *each instance*. Essentially, these two variables are shared across all instances of `Try`. When you instantiated the second `Try` object, the original two values were overwritten.

Making the two variables non-static will result in the calculations you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

AA and BB attributes are shared between all objects (and they were rewritten).

```
package pkgtry;

/**
 *
 * @author HeiLee
 * 
 */
public class Try {

 /* there is the mistake,

    public static int AA; 
    public static int BB;

    This attributes are shared between all objects.
*/
    public int AA; 
    public int BB;

     Try(int a, int b)
    {
        AA=a;
        BB=b;
    }
     int calculate()
    {
        int c;
        c=AA + BB;
        System.out.println(c);
        return 0;
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Try a = new Try(1,2);
        Try b = new Try(2,3);
        a.calculate();
        b.calculate();
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as long as you don't change the `c=Try.AA + Try.BB` line to `c = this.AA + this.BB`. Also, `AA` and `BB` are horrible names for instances variables.

Comment: Thank you! And yea, those names are horrible.!!